# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 1: Gradle Sync Error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, anko

I'm getting this error in my Kotlin project:

[image: Gradle error]

Here is my app's Gradle files:

[image]

[image]

I haven't really done anything to the project yet except add Kotlin and Anko dependencies. Not sure what's happening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known issue with Anko. It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/381).

You can try to exclude implicit `com.google.android:android` dependency from Anko's dependencies:

```
compile("org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
}
```

(Keep in mind as you are using separate Anko libraries - you may need to use exclusion in multiple pleces).

You can also try to update Gradle plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried using 3.0.0-alpha2, but was getting the same error. I changed it to 2.4.0-alpha7, based on the example Anko project on their github, and now it works.

Comment: Tough life of exploring alpha libraries. :) Great to hear you solved your issue!

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency inside you app-level app module :

```
// Anko
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:0.8.2' // sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:0.8.2' // In case you need support-v4 bindings
compile 'org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:0.8.2' // For appcompat-v7 bindings
```

Comment: That's actually where they are I think? Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As In your screenshot I can see that while adding Anko dependencies you didn't mention the Anko version , kindly mention that it should work fine post that.

Comment: It's actually mentioned in the top-level build file, as shown in the second image.

Answer (score 0):

Add like this too.
flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
  debug {
    dimension "default"
    ...
  }

release {
    dimension "default"
    ...
  }

foss {
    dimension "default"
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, its Google Repository which is missing. As you can see the ide itself is informing you about it.

Failed to resolve: com.google.android:android.2.3.1 which is Google Repository.

If you are connected to internet then simply click on Install Repository and Sync project in the Gradle Sync window. It will download the google repository and sync your project.

[image]
[image]